# Are there any details about the plot of the cancelled 5th season of the 4400?

Tags: tv, the-4400

The excellent Sci-Fi show '[The 4400](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4400)' was canceled abruptly after what some may consider one of the most interesting and open-ended cliffhangers in the series history:

> Essentially half of the population of Seattle and some unpopular cast members die from a [promicin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promicin) overdose spread by a "[The Naked Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Naked_Time)"-like disease.  The other half of Seattle and most of the surviving non-promicin powered regular characters gain random amazing powers.

Did [René Echevarria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Echevarria) or [Scott Peters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Peters_%28writer%29) give any interviews or leave any notes about where the series was headed?

Is there any information about what was planned for Season 5?

Comment: I seem to recall a recent rumour about this going into a comic book to tie up the loose ends.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, [The 4400 - Books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_4400#Books), there are some books set after the end of the series.  I haven't read them, but I'd check those for a continuation of the cliffhanger ending.

edit:  According to [this](http://4400.wikia.com/wiki/4400_Books#Welcome_to_Promise_City) (maybe spoilers for the books?), the last 2 books are set after the cliffhanger.